# Hypothesis test for lower circular distance in angular datasets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, circular-statistics

I need to know how I can test in directional statistics whether there is significant evidence of the circular distance between the mean of one dataset and certain angle being smaller than the distance between the circular mean of another dataset and that angle. The test should have the null hypothesis $H_0: \cos(\overline{\theta}_1 - \phi) \geq \cos(\overline{\theta}_2 - \phi)$. I think a non-parametric test, that assumes no distribution to be followed by the data will suffice (i will most likely use it with $\phi = 0$).

In the literature, I found a test for common mean direction, the Watson's Large-sample Nonparametric Test, but I do not know how or if it is possible to change the null hypothesis ($H_0: \overline\theta_1 = \overline\theta_2$) to make it the test I need.

Do you know of any solution?

Comment: What is your definition of smaller? If $10^\circ$ is smaller than $30^\circ$, then why is not $350^\circ$ smaller than $10^\circ$? It's a rotation of $20^\circ$ counter- or anti-clockwise in both cases. More abstractly put, the origin and even sense of rotation are conventional choices in directional statistics, so I can't see that "smaller" has a meaning unless you spell out what it is. Conversely, if you have angles for which closer to zero is of interest, it's not clear that your variable is truly circular.

Comment: Yes, i think a more precise statement will be the circular distance to $0^\circ$ to be smaller, then perhaps something like $H_0: 1-\cos(\mu_1) < 1 - \cos(\mu_2)$?. This will suffice for my purposes

Comment: If the origin is privileged and uniquely defined, then I think your problem is not really circular. Telling us what the variable is might make your question more vivid.

Comment: Im analyzing data that can be described as the angle between two branches in a tree. So far my angles are contained in an interval from about $0.002^\circ$ to $164^\circ$, and my interest for this test would arise from observations on the mean direction on different levels (or depths) of the tree. But i think now, as you pointed out, that in this case linear statistcs could cover my needs.

However i think now it may be interesting to have a proper statistic test for the distance hypothesis in the circle, as it covers the case where $350^\circ$ is viewed closer than $20^\circ$ to $0^\circ$

Comment: I would treat your problem as estimating a probability and do any inference via bootstrapping and a confidence interval, unless you can use biology to suggest a distribution.

Comment: Yes, i think that will suffice for this time. However, i think i will need a test for that null hypothesis in the future, so i will edit the question to show this.

Comment: It's just Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon, better approached by Somers' $d$, is it not? See e.g. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0007

Comment: But Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon seems to test if two populations are the same, how could it be adapted to test circular distances differences in directional statistics?

Comment: In essence my argument is that your variable is not really circular. A hallmark of a circular variable is (e.g.) that if $1^\circ$ is possible, then so is $359^\circ$, and it means almost the same; ditto 00:01 and 23:59 or 1 January and 31 December. Your application doesn't sound like that. See the paper I cited for a detailed discussion centred on $P(Y > X)$.